# How to make iTerm2 ls output colorful?

Tags: bash, iterm, color

I have been trying to get my iterm2 terminal colorful, but I am having very little success. I tried adding the following to my .bash_profile

```
# Set CLICOLOR if you want Ansi Colors in iTerm2
export CLICOLOR=1

# Set colors to match iTerm2 Terminal Colors
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

which helped get the ANSI colors at least, but my iterm2 terminal is still pretty boring-looking...

I am trying to get my directories to look one color, my files to look one color, and the stuff behind the $ sign on iterm2 to be one color, and my cursor to be one color. So far, I have managed to pull of changing the color of my cursor and directories, but everything else is still a boring plain white color.

I did this my going to Preferences->Profile and then messing with the colors there. Any advice you have is appreciated.

Any advice you have is appreciated.

Comment: You have done all you can do with Iterm - what you need to look for is how to do this in your shell and also how to make ls output coloured (for that see the ls man page and LSCOLORS (note no _ that is for other OSs))

Comment: Consider looking at https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash/ - while I don't like installing a huge package "just for colors" - they have a number of examples in their themes directory you can directly paste.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _directories in one colour_. If you refer the output of the `ls` command, iTerm can't help you here, because iTerm does not know anything about the commands running in it. As for "the stuff after $", do you mean shell variables ($TERM, $PATH,...)?

Comment: Setting `TERM`is fine. Since you mention `CLICOLOR`. I guess you are interested in colorized output of `ls`. What do you see, when you do a `ls -lG`?

Answer (score 0):

`ls -G` should show you the directory listing with colors. Default iTerm2 color scheme normally presents this quite fine, for instance, Directories are blue, symlinks are purple.

Comment: BSD `ls` has no `--color` option; that's recognized by GNU `ls`. The BSD equivalent is `-G`.

Comment: Oops, @chepner, might have either installed a newer `bash` or been on a remote server when I was testing. Thanks for the correction, editing it in.

Answer (score 0):

Command `man ls` will show some flags to list and show colors in the iterm2 and all other terminals.

Also need to check your iterm color profile settings and pick colors. Normally these are defaulted and don’t need to be touched.

All your answers are here:

https://github.com/alebcay/awesome-shell

https://github.com/k4m4/terminals-are-sexy

Look up any awesome lists for more command line / shell configurations here:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome

The list contains more than what you’re asking for but there are many awesome lists for the terminal.

Comment: The “answers” you linked don’t directly address the question.  It’s better to summarize your answer here and link to your supporting information.